# Swift : Exception while navigating UIViewController to UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

In AppDelegate I check if user session list then move to user home(display two buttons) else to login page.  Form login page after login sending to user home.

LoginView is `UIViewController`
UserHome is `UIViewController`

When I click "Get Report " on UserHome I want to display some report in table
ReportView is `UITableViewController`

Here is the application code

**AppDelegate**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


    let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let isUserLoggedIn:Bool = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isUserLoggedIn")

    if(!isUserLoggedIn){
        let loginVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginvc") as!  LoginVC

        window!.rootViewController = loginVC

        window!.makeKeyAndVisible();

    }else{

let userhome = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("userhome") as!  UserHomeViewController

            window!.rootViewController = userhome
            window!.makeKeyAndVisible();


 }


    return true
}
```

**LoginView**

After succes response from rest service

```
let userhome = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("user home") as! UserHomeViewController
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.presentViewController(userhome, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
```

**On Get Report I have**

```
@IBAction func getReport(sender: UIButton) {

    let reportview = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("reportvc") as! ReportViewController

    //Excepetion
    self.presentViewController(reportview, animated: true, completion: nil)

    //nothing happens
    //self.navigationController?.presentViewController(reportview, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**ReportViewCOntroller is just has noting. Base methods implemented**

```
class FSMSOListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var soList = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    soList = ["E7677","E7678","E7679","E7680"]

    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableView.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")


        }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return soList.count

}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
        "cell",
        forIndexPath: indexPath) //make the cell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.soList[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

**Exception is**

> 2016-04-09 12:26:19.415 AkunaConnect[13163:943688] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'must pass a class of kind UITableViewCell'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102cf9e65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104a39deb objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102cf9d9d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
>       3   UIKit                               0x0000000103662b01 -[UITableView registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:] + 285
>       4   AkunaConnect                        0x0000000102ad783f _TFC12AkunaConnect28FSMSOListTableViewController11viewDidLoadfS0_FT_T_ + 623
>       5   AkunaConnect                        0x0000000102ad78f2 _TToFC12AkunaConnect28FSMSOListTableViewController11viewDidLoadfS0_FT_T_ + 34
>       6   UIKit                               0x00000001036acf98 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1198
>       7   UIKit                               0x00000001036ad2e7 -[UIViewController view] + 27
>       8   UIKit                               0x0000000103e57f87 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 87
>       9   UIKit                               0x000000010367cf62 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 133
>       10  UIKit                               0x00000001036bfc8c -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 4002
>       11  UIKit                               0x00000001036c2f2c -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 489
>       12  UIKit                               0x00000001036c2a3b -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 179
>       13  AkunaConnect                        0x0000000102ad688d _TFC12AkunaConnect17FLMViewController9getReportfS0_FCSo8UIButtonT_ + 621
>       14  AkunaConnect                        0x0000000102ad69ea _TToFC12AkunaConnect17FLMViewController9getReportfS0_FCSo8UIButtonT_ + 58
>       15  UIKit                               0x0000000103518194 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
>       16  UIKit                               0x00000001036876fc -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
>       17  UIKit                               0x00000001036879c8 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
>       18  UIKit                               0x0000000103686af8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
>       19  UIKit                               0x000000010358749b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
>       20  UIKit                               0x00000001035881d0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
>       21  UIKit                               0x0000000103536b66 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
>       22  UIKit                               0x0000000103510d97 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6844
>       23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102c25a31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>       24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102c1b95c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
>       25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102c1ae13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
>       26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102c1a828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
>       27  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010730fad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
>       28  UIKit                               0x0000000103516610 UIApplicationMain + 171
>       29  AkunaConnect                        0x0000000102ad96cd main + 109
>       30  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010554292d start + 1
>       31  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to register a tableview class instance as a UITableViewCell in ** FSMSOListTableViewController** class.

*This may help you*:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    soList = ["E7677","E7678","E7679","E7680"]
     self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

}
```

Comment: I get compilation error for UITableViewCellStyleDefault but worked for below   `self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")`

Answer (score 0):

Use this
`table.register(UITableViewCell.self , forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")`
instead of
`table.register(UITableView.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")`